# Getting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException issue while using the Native query in JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the `SQLGrammarException` exception while using the following code

Please check the my Repository class which are as follow

```
package repository;

package repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import entity.UserInfo;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInfo, Integer> {
    
    
    @Query("select u from UserInfo u")
    public List<UserInfo> getAllUsers();

    
    /// I AM GETTING THE ISSUE IN THE FOLLOWING QUERY WHICH ARE AS BELOW
    @Query(value = "select u From UserInfo u WHERE u.name= :n",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<UserInfo> getUserByName(@Param("n") String name);

    
    
}
```

Now please check my Service class which are as follow

```
package service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.learning.sql_learning.SqlLearningApplication;

import entity.PaymentInfo;
import entity.UserInfo;
import repository.PaymentRepository;
import repository.UserRepository;
import transaction.MyExcecption;
import transaction.RequestUser;
import transaction.UserAcknowlegment;

@Service
public class TransactionService {

    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqlLearningApplication.class);

    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public List<UserInfo> getAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userRepository.getAllUsers();
    }

    public List<UserInfo> getUserByName(String name) {
        return userRepository.getUserByName(name);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Please check my database which consists the record.

[image]

I have searched here in SO but did not get the proper solutions on it, Here there was the same issue in SO, but not working for me, please help me on it

I am getting the following exception while running the `getUserByName()` rest API

> {
> "timestamp": "2021-08-13T07:51:30.538+00:00",
> "status": 500,
> "error": "Internal Server Error",
> "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy106.getUserByName(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat service.TransactionService.getUserByName(TransactionService.java:67)\r\n\tat service.TransactionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a688df0.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)\r\n\tat service.TransactionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7bb3b0ca.getUserByName()\r\n\tat controller.MyController.getUserByName(MyController.java:116)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1169)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 63 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'another_test.userinfo' doesn't exist\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)\r\n\t... 94 more\r\n",
> "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
> "path": "/getUserByName"
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid nativeQuery.

That would be the correct nativeQuery:

```
@Query(value = "select * From UserInfo u WHERE u.name= :n",nativeQuery = true)
List<UserInfo> getUserByName(@Param("n") String name);
```

But I doubt that you really want to execute a native query (SQL) but a JPQL query. So you can remove the nativeQuery=true

```
@Query(value = "select u From UserInfo u WHERE u.name= :n")
List<UserInfo> getUserByName(@Param("n") String name);
```

And now this query can be generate by Spring Data JPA so you will not need the Query at all:

```
List<UserInfo> findByName(String name);
```

Comment: Yes it is working fine now, I removed the **nativeQuery** in the Query. One more question Sir, can we use the `@RequestParam` and `Pathvariable` in above query in **POST** request

Comment: Yes simply change the annotation Service to @RestController.